How do you know you have an ArrayIterator in a PHP extension
In SaxonC PHP extension (written in C++) I am writing utility to allow users to write custom functions in their PHP script which will get called in XSLT, XPath or XQuery. Therefore we have to handle a number of PHP native return types from the user function. This I can do without problem, except for ArrayIterators. We get back a zval which can be an ArrayIterator. But how can I check if it is actually an ArrayIterator type in the PHP internals using the Zend framework written in C++ code?
See the code snippet below:
zval retval;
int value = (int)Z_TYPE_P(&retval)

The value gives zero (i.e. IS_UNDEF) when I know its should be an ArrayIterator and not IS_OBJECT. How can I check for ArrayIterator?

You probably should check for Traversable objects in general using instanceof_function(Z_OBJCE_P(data), zend_ce_traversable).
If the type of the retval is IS_UNDEF after calling a user function, this means the function threw an exception.
Aside: you can just use Z_TYPE(retval) instead of Z_TYPE_P(&retval)

Thanks. Yes I have now checked fr IS_UNDEF and thrown an exception

Z_TYPE(retval) == IS_OBJECT &&
instanceof_function(Z_OBJCE(retval), spl_ce_ArrayIterator)

spl_ce_ArrayIterator is declared in spl_array.h

Thanks for our answer which looks good. But I am getting a seg error. function sequenceOfArraysParamC($arr1){$array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world"); return $array->getIterable(); }  lldb output of the crash:  thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x29) frame #0: 0x000000010036c088 phpinstanceof_function_slow + 12 phpinstanceof_function_slow: -> 0x10036c088 <+12>: ldr x8, [x8, #0x10]

For context the retval comes from call_user_function(CG(function_table), (zval*)callOnObj, &function_name, &retval, argLength, params)

Can you check whether spl_ce_ArrayIterator is a null_ptr?

This is the PHP function:
  $array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
    return $array->getIterable();
}```

This comes back as true:Z_TYPE_P(&retval) == IS_UNDEF

Also this is false: Z_OBJCE_P(&retval) == nullptr

Did you remove the precondition Z_TYPE_P(&retval) == IS_OBJECT?

Yes I did. the IS_OBJECT check is false.

It seems that the function you called did not set a return value.

That is strange because we have the return statement in the function return $array->getIterator(); if I change it to return 1; we get a number returned.

I think I figured out the problem. The ArrayIterator must be called on an ArrayObject

But I am still confused because I thought could create an ArrayIterator  from an Array

I didn't have a full picture of your utility, but to create an ArrayIterator from an array. You can just do new ArrayIterator($array).

How can I create an ArrayIterator in an PHP extension? This might be a separate question.

I have created the Iterator snippet of the code: zend_call_method_with_1_params(Z_OBJ(retval), spl_ce_ArrayIterator, &spl_ce_ArrayIterator->constructor, "__construct", NULL, &arrval);

You need to init the zval first object_init_ex(&retval, spl_ce_ArrayIterator). I suggest you create a new question because SO keeps asking me to avoid extended discussions in comments.

Yes I did init the zval first. If I need ask any more questions I will create a new question. Thanks
